# MongoTemplate find not returning results

Tags: mongodb

MongoTemplate not returning results.

Json:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51acf6ab0d5d46077ae12b2a"), 
  "docType" : "row",
  "value" : {
    "entity" : {
      "@id" : "1111",
      "@version" : "3434",
      "name" : "XY XY",
      "listId" : 28,
      "listCode" : "BS",
      "entityType" : "03",
      "createdDate" : "09/12/2006",
      "lastUpdateDate" : "04/20/2011",
      "source" : "CCC",
      "address1" : "XXXXXXXX",
      "city" : "CITY",
      "country" : "CO",
      "countryName" : "COUNTRY NAME"    

    }
  },
  "createdDate" : ISODate("2013-06-03T20:03:55.127Z"),
  "createdBy" : "Test"
}
```

Query:

```
queryy = new Query(Criteria.where("docType").is("row").andOperator(Criteria.where("value.entity.city").is("CITY")));
```

Above query doesn't return any result back.

Am I missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = new Query(Criteria.where("docType").is("row")
                 .and("value.entity.city").is("CITY"));
```

You're code doesn't need the `andOperator` function (as that translates to `$and`). It just needs multiple criteria using `and`.

And, you can use `query.toString()` to see what the output would be of the query (and compare it to what you might have used in the MongoDB shell.